# Indexing issue when appending two pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on dummifying a column of zipcodes in pandas so I can build a random forest model in sklearn.  Here is my code:

`forest_test_features = test_df[['sqft_lot', 'floors', 'waterfront', 
     'view', 'condition', 'grade', 'sqft_above', 'sqft_basement', 
     'yr_built', 'yr_renovated']]
forest_test_features.append(pd.get_dummies(test_df['zipcode']))
forest_test_target = test_df['price']`

I get a runtime warning, and then my model's R^2 score is much lower than when I simply leave zipcode in the model without dummifying, suggesting something went wrong.  pd.get_dummies returns a dataframe, and I think the problem is in the fact that this dataframe and forest_test_features are in two different orders, but I am unsure of how to proceed.  The indexes are still correct (zipcode 98144 maps to a '1' in the '98144' column of get_dummies return.)

I also get this warning: RuntimeWarning: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int', sort order is undefined for incomparable objects
  result = result.union(other)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the order. I guess you have a forest_train_features dataframe. you can do this:

```
feats = forest_test_features.keys()
model = RandomForestRegressor()
model.fit(forest_train_features[feats], forest_train_features['price'])
prediction = model.predict(forest_test_features[feats])
```

the columns should be in the same order then. 
You can also do the same preprocessing for the train and test in the same DataFrame and then split it

Comment: You might be confusing DataFrame.concat() with DataFrame.append().  The column order is not an issue.

Your comment did make me realize that my preprocessing is a little overcomplicated.